# Adding a vertex in graph in adjacent matrix repersentation

Tags: graphs

In website geeksforgeeks i read that adding a vertex to graph in adjacent matrix takes O(V^2) time but i am not getting it. It requires adding a row and a column which should take linear time ?
I am a beginner hence forgive me for such a question

Link:- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/

Comment: Try to implement it yourself and see how you (a) get _O(1)_ query and (b) what you need to do to extend the graph.  When you _add a column_ you actually have to replace the entire row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It more or less depends on the implementation. If you have implemented the matrix using linked lists (which isn't what we usually do), then adding a new vertex in $G$ will be linear in the number of vertices of $G$. But we don't usually use linked lists because then reading/checking an edge will take $V(G)^2$ time.

To allow random/constant time access of the adjacency matrix, we need to use fixed-size arrays of arrays (or matrix). Now, when you add new vertex, we are required to copy the whole matrix into a bigger size matrix: hence the quadratic time.

Generally, we use $vectors$ instead of $arrays$ which hold *extra hidden memory*, and hence it will indeed be linear time to add a vertex on average. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-in-cpp-stl/

Comment: amortized complexity*

Answer (score 0):

Yes will takes *O(V<sup>2</sup>)*, Suppose you have a small graph from vertices 1, 2, 3, 4
and each vertex connected to each other, So you have

```
1 [2, 3, 4]
2 [1, 3, 4]
3 [1, 2, 4]
4 [1, 2, 3]
```

To add this graph you need to loop for each vertex and add an edge (a link) to V-1 using LinkedList

You will find that the time complexity V * (V-1) which it's *O(V<sup>2</sup>)*